# Why variable of type NSDate does not initialise in initialiser?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to init `NSDate` variable in initialiser with `NSString` argument by `NSDateFormatter` and as a result I get null. What is the problem?
Thank you!
Sorry for my english.

```objc
@interface NewsEntity ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *newsSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *newsTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *newsDescription;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *imageUrl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *pubDate;

@end

@implementation NewsEntity

- (instancetype)initWithNewsSource:(NSString *)newsSource withNewsTitle:(NSString *)newsTitle withNewsDescription:(NSString *)newsDescription withImgeUrl:(NSURL *)imageUrl withPubDateString:(NSString *)pubDateString {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _newsSource = newsSource;
        _newsTitle = newsTitle;
        _newsDescription = newsDescription;
        _imageUrl = imageUrl;

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
        _pubDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:pubDateString];

        NSLog(@"Date: %@", _pubDate);
        NSLog(@"Date string: %@", pubDateString);

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

```objc
@interface NewsData ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dataSources;
@property (atomic) NSUInteger parsingFromDataSourcesComplete;
@property (strong, atomic) NSMutableArray *listOfNewsEntities;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *newsTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *newsDescription;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageUrlString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *pubDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *element;

@end

@implementation NewsData

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dataSources = @[FIRST_SOURCE_URL, SECOND_SOURCE_URL];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)getNewsData {
    for (NSString *dataSource in self.dataSources) {
        self.listOfNewsEntities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataSource];
        NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [xmlParser parse];
        });
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    self.element = elementName;

    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        self.newsTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.newsDescription = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.pubDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        self.imageUrlString = nil;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]) {
        self.imageUrlString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [self.newsTitle appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [self.newsDescription appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [self.pubDate appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        NewsEntity *newsEntity = [[NewsEntity alloc] initWithNewsSource:nil withNewsTitle:self.newsTitle withNewsDescription:self.newsDescription withImgeUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageUrlString] withPubDateString:self.pubDate];

        [self.listOfNewsEntities addObject:newsEntity];
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self prepareForSendingInfo];
    });
}

- (void)prepareForSendingInfo {
    self.parsingFromDataSourcesComplete++;
    if (self.parsingFromDataSourcesComplete == self.dataSources.count) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_NEWS_INFO_IS_READY object:self.listOfNewsEntities];
    }
}

@end
```

Example of output:

```
2015-06-04 18:21:34.384 TestAssignmentR[70762:12799790] Date: (null)  

2015-06-04 18:21:34.384 TestAssignmentR[70762:12799790] Date string: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 18:07:56 +0300  

2015-06-04 18:21:34.385 TestAssignmentR[70762:12799790] Date: (null)  

2015-06-04 18:21:34.385 TestAssignmentR[70762:12799790] Date string: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 18:05:56 +0300  

2015-06-04 18:21:34.386 TestAssignmentR[70762:12799790] Date: (null)  

2015-06-04 18:21:34.386 TestAssignmentR[70762:12799790] Date string: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 18:05:17 +0300
```

### UPD:

I have changed dateFormatter as you offered me, but it did not help.
The problem must be somewhere in NewsData class.
Also I tried this example, and it works fine:

```objc
@interface TestDateFormatter ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *date;

@end

@implementation TestDateFormatter

- (instancetype)initWithDateString:(NSString *)dateString {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
        _date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
        NSLog(@"%@", _date);
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *dateString = @"Wed, 03 Jun 2015 13:17:00 +0300";
    TestDateFormatter *test = [[TestDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateString:dateString];
}

@end
```

Comment: Because the date format you provide does not actually match the date format that is present in your string?!

Comment: You can debug these sorts of issues using by calling `-getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` instead of `-dateFromString`. It will tell you the range of the string that it successfully parsed, which will help isolate the part it didn't parse. There's also an error output parameter which may provide additional information about any failure.

Comment: Your code will also see the bug described in [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: Thank you! I gonna check that.

Comment: @KenThomases, Thank you, so much! That method finally  solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

The date formatting specifier is not correct.  You want `ZZZ` for the timezone offset:

```
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
                            ^^^
```

Also I think it's fairly unusual to do this format conversion in the `init` method; it would be much more flexible to pass in an already initialized `NSDate` object and then the `init` method does not need to make assumptions about the format used to represent the date within the string.  That can be left to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your date format string in other way. Just print current date with your format and you'll see how input string should look

You have a problem in timezone format, it should be just Z:

```
NSString *pubDateString = @"Thu, 04 Jun 2015 18:05:17 +0300";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *pubDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:pubDateString];
NSString *nowDateStringValue = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Date: %@", pubDate);
NSLog(@"Date string: %@", pubDateString);
NSLog(@"Now: %@", nowDateStringValue);




2015-06-05 10:56:55.443 Test[19514:4492358] Date: 2015-06-04 15:05:17 +0000
2015-06-05 10:56:55.443 Test[19514:4492358] Date string: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 18:05:17 +0300
2015-06-05 10:56:55.444 Test[19514:4492358] Now: Fri, 05 Jun 2015 10:56:55 GMT+3
```

Comment: @ArtemAK can't compile your code because TestDateFormatter doesn't declared properly: you declare it as `@interface TestDateFormatter ()` but it should be `@interface TestDateFormatter : NSObject`, for me everything works fine. It output `Wed, 03 Jun 2015 13:17:00 +0300` and 
` 2015-06-03 10:17:00 +0000`

Answer (score 1):

In fact your date formatter string does not match the date strings you provide. You should try the following date formatter string instead:

```
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
```

It uses `Z` instead of `zzz` and returns the proper result:

> Date: 2015-06-04 15:07:56 +0000
>   Date string: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 18:07:56 +0300

Take a look at the [Unicode Locale Data Markup Language](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for all the possible date pattern and what kind of information they match

> Z, ZZ and ZZZ: The ISO8601 basic format with hours, minutes and optional seconds fields. The format is equivalent to RFC 822 zone format (when optional seconds field is absent). This is equivalent to the "xxxx" specifier.

In your case one Z will match timezones like `-0800` and `+0300` - exactly what you want.

Comment: @ArtemAK I do not really understand what problem still exists? Is it still printing (null)? have you tried the debugging tips offered in the comments to your question?

Comment: problem finally solved with method -getObjectValue:forString:range:error:.
So, thank you!